# Checking a different directory for a Program

Tags: c, path

So I am working on a small project and I have this function:

```
void call_execve(char *cmd)
{
    int i;
    char bin[5];
    char full_cmd[100];

    strcpy(bin, "/bin/");

    strcat(full_cmd, bin);
    strcat(full_cmd, cmd);

    if(fork() == 0) {
        i = execve(full_cmd, my_argv, my_envp);
        if(i < 0) {
            printf("%s: %s\n", full_cmd, "command not found");
            exit(1);        
        }
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

I guess my brain just isn't thinking tonight, I need to make it check the /usr/bin directory for the program or shell command.

I know I can use the $PATH variable, but I am unsure how to work with it via the C Language. It would be great if you could re-write this function to either **execute the program from the /usr/bin directory** or **use $PATH to execute the program**

Thank you in advance.

GeissT.

Comment: `char bin[5];` not enough space for `"/bin/"`. In the `strcat(full_cmd, ...)` calls `full_cmd` has an invalid value (it hasn't been initialized)

Comment: But /bin/ is 5 characters? Or do the slashes add a few more characters?

Comment: there is a terminating `'\0'` in all strings.

Comment: Maybe you just want `system` or `popen`?

Comment: It's for a stand-alone shell, so I shouldn't really use BASH as a front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [execvp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) library function mimics the shell search inside `$PATH` and then call `execve`.

If you want on the contrary to execute a program whose file path is known to you (e.g. `/usr/bin/mail`) then just call `execve` with the complete path as the first *filename* argument.

Comment: Okay, so if I let the user type a command such as _ls_ or _make_ then will _execvp_ search for the program in the needed directorys by just passing it the command?

Comment: `execvp` (or `execve` or other `exec*` functions) has nothing to do with what the user types. It is a function to execute a program. And with `execvp` and related functions, the `$PATH` is searched, but with `execve` it is not.

Comment: What I mean, is can I call **execvp(full_cmd)** ? And pass the existing arguments to it?

Comment: You'll call `execlp("make", "-j", "all", NULL)` which will replace the current program by `make`; if you want to run a program from inside another one, consider also the `system` or `popen` functions.

Comment: Okay sounds good :) The project I am doing is a basic Linux Shell, so would this be suitable?

Comment: It is probably a homework, so you could consider that searching the `PATH` by yourself (without using `execvp`) is part of the exercise. Ask your teacher for more!

Comment: This is a hobby project, not homework. Using the **system()** function uses the default shell. being bash, so this wouldnt seem to be a standalone shell.

Comment: Look into the source code of SASH http://members.tip.net.au/~dbell/programs/sash-3.7.tar.gz

Comment: I just took a quick peek at it. This looks good, but I don't want to re-write the Linux Kernels commands, I want to use the existing commands, does BASH re-write the commands? If so then I might consider your suggestion.

Comment: Shell have no "linux kernel commands" [I don't understand what you call like that], but they do use system calls. And you'll need to use syscalls in your shell (e.g. `chdir`, `dup2`, `pipe`..).

Comment: Okay, yeah my bad :P

So I would need to re-write the commands in order to create a completely different shell?

Comment: You'll need *builtin shell commands* inside your shell, and some of them  (e.g. `cd`) would interface syscalls.

Comment: Ah yeah.

Now I am with you, okay thanks, seems as if SASH would be a perfect starting place for me then :)

Thank you Basile :)

Answer (score 1):

From the `exec(3)` man page:

> The  `execlp()`,  `execvp()`, and `execvpe()` functions duplicate the actions
>          of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified file‐
>          name does not contain a slash (/) character.  The file is sought in the
>          colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the `PATH` environment  variable.

Comment: Okay, so if I use the _execlp()_ function it will search the $PATH directorys?

Comment: @GeissT: *Any* of the `exec*p*()` functions will search `$PATH`, provided no path is specified in the command.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. So I can just pass _exec*p*_ the command that is entered with no need for the directory?

Comment: Can this take the existing parameters that the function used in my question take?

Comment: Take some time to review the documentation before asking naive questions like that.